# ¿Cómo trabajar mi proyecto de GitHub en dos ordenadores distintos?

Tags: github, git-clone

¿qué tal andan?. Primero quiero pedir disculpas si es una pregunta repetida, pero sinceramente creo no haber encontrado el tema adecuado a lo que pregunto.

Estoy cursando para convertirme en Front-End, por lo que estoy utilizando GitHub para presentar mis entregas y demás.
Pero tengo dudas sobre cómo hacer para trabajar un mismo proyecto en la rama main desde dos ordenadores distintos.

El proyecto lo tengo montado en mi computadora de escritorio, pero por cuestiones de tiempos, necesitaría poder trabajar ese mismo proyecto desde mi notebook.

Lo que yo hice es clonar el proyecto en mi notebook con el "**git clone (acá el enlace)**"
Lo abro con el Visual Studio Code y utilizo un comando para traerme la carpeta de node_modules con "npm install".

Ahora, supongamos que estoy trabajando el proyecto, hago modificaciones, suprimo y añado cosas.
Lógicamente, hago un commit y luego un push. ¿cómo hago para que los cambios que hice en la notebook, se guarden en mi proyecto de github?
Y después, ¿cómo traigo esos cambios que hice en la notebook, en mi pc de escritorio?.
Tengo entendido que es con el git pull para traer los cambios realizados.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo y espero una pronta respuesta.

Comment: Así como lo dices con git pull no deberías de necesitar nada más, igual puedes usar  el control de versiones de VS Code para encargarte de manejar todo eso. Si hay algo pendiente de descargar te aparecerá el mensaje, igual tienes la opción de que haga `git fetch` cada vez que abres el proyecto.

Comment: @René Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Me he puesto a trabajar en mi código desde la notebook (clonado), y pude hacer cambios y subirlos sin problemas a github. Sólo me faltaría probar si me funciona en la pc de escritorio (desde donde creé el repo) lo del git pull o fetch para traerme el nuevo estado de mi repo en git!

Comment: Sólo tienes que hacerte el hábito de siempre commitear y pushear antes de dejar un computador, y siempre hacer git pull al empezar en el otro. O sino, tendrás que hacer merge de conflictos para juntar el código. Yo lo que hago en trabajar en ramas distintas.

Comment: @ffflabs Muchas gracias por contestar! He hecho eso el otro dia y funcionó bien. Sobre todo porque en ambas computadoras tengo iniciado y configurado mi cuenta de git bash. Así que cada cambio que hago en mi proyecto y que luego pusheo, al hacer git pull en la otra compu, me trae esos cambios y viceversa. Muchas gracias por responder! Un abrazo.